# IBM Worklight login Page

Tags: authentication, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I'm in the process of building an end-to-end application.

I want to incorporate a simple login page that will verify credentials against a database. I need the page to be the first page that is displayed when I run the application. I have read the various modules on authentication but their design is a little different.

I have found other resources on like [Sunil's notes on how to enable form-based login](http://wpcertification.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/how-to-enable-authentication-in.html) but this involves modifying auth.js that isn't present in Worklight v6.0.

I'm also unsure if I should use the single sign on approach, but that would mean getting additional software like Websphere Portal which I'm not too keen on.

FYI, my UI is entirely built using dojo/dojo mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Worklight 6.0? If you are seeing some of our older sample projects may help you out. You should check out one of our older samples based around form-based authentication, here is a link to all tutorials and samples:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html

Here is a link to form based authentication tutorial and below the form based authentication sample:

Tutorial: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf

Sample: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/FormBasedAuthenticationProject.zip